# can i uninstall software centre from 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

can i uninstall software centre from 14.04?

It will not allow me to install anything from there, or delete anything. 
I have been using Synaptic and GDebi for all installs. (perfectly happy with that.)
Software Centre seems to be unneccesary, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your problem is the following command.

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

**Note:** Your question is a possible duplicate of [How do I remove the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240733/how-do-i-remove-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center --purge
```

I don't know if it is related to uninstalling the software center, but in whenever I did uninstalled it I had a weird SSO client error on every system start. Nothing serious, just the typical "Ubuntu has experienced a problem" message box.